# Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _WinMain@16

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio

Вот скрин ошибки в visual studio:
[image: screen]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так.
ОС: Windows 7 64bit,
ПО: Visual Studio Professional 2012 32bit

PS: Первый раз в Си.. Не советуйте, пожалуйста, линукс, дайте сначала с этим разобраться.

Comment: вместо `void main()` пишите хотя бы `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` (если я правильно помню.

А лучше - не пишите это ручками, а дайте студии сгенерировать самостоятельно.

Comment: А разве в MSVS есть компилятор Си?

Comment: а мы пишем на си, но компилируем как с++)

Comment: @SoloMio там на скриншоте у файла расширение cpp, то есть судя по всему это С++ проект, в коде которого используются только средства Си

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо создавать Win32 Console Application, а не Win32 Project. (Названия могут немного варъироваться в разных студиях)